# Setting raster cell value to null if below threshold value in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

Why is my ArcPy script in ArcGIS 10.1 failing to set null cell values below three standard deviations beyond the mean?

```
import arcpy, sys, os

#Accept input and output raster
inRas = sys.argv[1]
outRas = sys.argv[2]

#Pull mean and standard deviation from input raster
meanie = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRas, "MEAN")
meanres = meanie.getOutput(0)
meanfloat = float(meanres)

stdev = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRas, "STD")
stdres = stdev.getOutput(0)
stdfloat = float(stdres)

#Calculate threshold value
threshold = meanfloat + (3 * stdfloat)
threstring = str(threshold)

#Create where clause
whereClause = "VALUE < " + threstring

#Test output
arcpy.AddMessage (whereClause)

#Run SetNull
outRas = arcpy.SetNull(inRas, inRas, whereClause)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File       "Z:<directory-redacted>\Nullify.py", line 27, in <module>
outRas = arcpy.SetNull(inRas, inRas, whereClause)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SetNull'

Failed to execute (Nullifiy).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arcpy.SetNull does not exist.  You are wanting arpy.sa.SetNull.

[Here's the SetNull page for 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000007000000).
If you notice in some of the examples there is:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
```

and you see that SetNull is used, but the import * from arcpy.sa drops the arcpy.sa from arcpy.sa.SetNull.  And be sure to check out the spatial analyst license